# C Programming: How to delete a single record from a file

Tags: c

I'm trying to delete a record from a file, by copying all of the records to a temporary file, except the one to be deleted. Then I delete the old file and rename the temporary file. Before renaming, I'm testing to see if the data actually transfers, but when I enter the prompted date and details, the program just freezes, even though the data I enter is from a record in the file. Can anyone help?

Here's the code:

```
void del_income() {
    Income I;
    Delete D;
    FILE *INCOME = fopen("C:\\income.txt", "a");
    FILE *TEMP = fopen("C:\\temporary.txt", "a");
    printf("Enter date of record to be deleted:");
    scanf("%s", D.date);
    printf("Enter job details of records to be deleted:");
    scanf("%s", D.details);
    while (1) {
        fscanf(INCOME, "%s %s %s %d %d %d %d %d",
               I.date, I.details, I.vehicleno, &I.rate, &I.hours, &I.subtotal,
               &I.vat, &I.total);
        if (feof(INCOME))
            break;
        if (strcmp(I.date, D.date) == 1 && strcmp(I.details, D.details) == 1)
            fprintf(TEMP, "%s %s %s %d %d %d %d %d",
                    I.date, I.details, I.vehicleno, I.rate, I.hours, I.subtotal,
                    I.vat, I.total);
    }
    fclose(INCOME);
    fclose(TEMP);
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mre], including definitions of `Income` and `Delete`, a complete program including all `#include` directives and a `main` function, contents of `income.txt`, and sample input.

Comment: Meanwhile: Do not rely on `feof(INCOME)`. Instead, test the return value of `fscanf`. Do not rely on `strcmp` to return 1. The only guarantee from the C standard is that it return a value greater than 0 to indicate “greater than”.

Comment: Pay attention to the modes you use with `fopen()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `INCOME` should be open with mode `"r"`, not `"a"`
- `TEMP` should be open with mode `"w"`, not `"a"`
- return values from `fopen` and `scanf` should be tested to avoid undefined behavior on errors.
- `if (feof(INCOME))` is not the proper way to test for end of file, you should instead check if `fscanf()` succeeded at converting 8 values: it should return 8. Any other return value is either a format error, missing fields or the end of file.
- `strcmp(I.date, D.date) == 1` is incorrect: `strcmp()` returns `0` for identical strings, `< 0` if `I.date` is lexicographically before `D.date` and `> 0` if it compares greater. You should change your tests to:

  ```
  if (strcmp(I.date, D.date) != 0 || strcmp(I.details, D.details) != 0)
  ```
- you should add a trailing newline in `fprintf(TEMP, "%s %s %s %d %d %d %d %d", ...)`
- conversion formats for strings `%s` should specify the maximum number of characters to store to the destination arrays to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input. For example if `D.date` is an array of 50 bytes, you should write:

  ```
  if (scanf("%49s", D.date) != 1) { /* handle input error */ }
  ```